# It is correct to group JComponent related classes in same package?

Tags: java, swing, package

I have a main package "UI" where i have all classes of my Swing Application.

In this package i extended JTree, JTable and some more components, and also made some custom renderers, custom models for them.

It is ok to group several classes related to a JComponent in their own package?

For example :

- `package ui.CustomTable`

  - `CustomJTable`
  - `CustomJTableModel`
  - `JTableColumnRenderer`
- `package ui.MYJList`

  - `MYJList`
  - `MyJListModel`
  - `MyJListCellRenderer`

I'm new in Software Engineering, it's my first job and I am asking you because i am "afraid" of breaking any OOP code conventions.

Comment: You extended `JTable` and `JTree` which is probably more 'wrong' then anything you do 'wrong' with your package structure as there is normally no need to extend those components. Re-structuring your packages is something that any decent IDE can do in a matter of seconds, so that can be easily fixed afterwards

Comment: thank you for your advice, i was overriding  `public String convertValueToText(Object value, boolean selected,
            boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
            boolean hasFocus)` for getting the text to display from my objects, but i guess my tree model isn't correct

Comment: Also, i had to extend the `JTable` because i made a custom paint for the background ( stripes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is ok to group several classes related to a JComponent in their own package?

Certainly.  In fact, it can be quite advantageous to have Swing classes in appropriate packages, especially when deployed using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

JWS can organize download, updates and security levels per Jar, so if each package is in a Jar, it means each package is only downloaded & cached, updated or checked for valid digital signature/security levels **if needed.**

Also note that renderers (or PLAFs) might change more frequently than other components when management decides the app. needs a 'different, more modern (than 4 months ago) look'.

Comment: See also the default [_package-private_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) access modifier.

Comment: @trashgod  `package-private` - My learn item of the day.   Used it a lot, only just associated that term with it.

Answer (score 1):

As a general guide, you could look at the package structure of the standard components that you are subclassing and map it to your own structure. You could use classes like so:

```
ui.CustomTable
ui.CustomList
ui.CustomListModel
ui.table.CustomTableColumnRenderer
```

It is better to have a consistent naming convention for class names.